# How to change the product category menu in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I want to change the product category menu style on the Woocommerce widgets but I can't find where to make the change. So far I've only found this. Where are the appropriate HTML tags?

```
<aside class="span4">
    <div class="aside-wrap">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('Woocommerce Sidebar'); ?>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Now grammatically correct and hopefully can be read. It is still unclear where the include code is located in the woocommerce environment overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your functions.php or simillar files, there will `widgets_init` hook using `register_sidebar` to register `Woocommerce Sidebar`.